# text color of google search natural list is abnormal

Tags: google-chrome

how to reset the text color of google search result. After I sign in to my google account, the text color of google search result has become low color contrast. This problem is happening in my phone, pc and every browser.

[left:after sign in. Right: before sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MpcX.png)

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me also. Here is a fix for now:

- on google, click up-right google profile image, then click "my account"
- click "activity controls" under "Personal info & privacy"
- turn **off** "Your searches and browsing activity (paused)"

Then your link colors will be fixed (blue again)